# how iterate ArrayCollection in symfony2 Controller

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I want to iterate `ArrayCollection` instance in Symfony2 Controller, What is the easiest way?

edit:

I thought it would work like normal array in php but I got error on this code:

```
foreach ($arrayCollectionInc as $Inc) {

}
```

Comment: You forgot to include what you've tried

Comment: `foreach($collection as $item){ ... }`

Comment: What was an error? `ArrayCollection` extends `Collection` which in turn implements `IteratorAggregate` and `ArrayAccess` ---> `foreach` should be possible...

Comment: and what error would that be ?

Comment: Hmmm.. I always got some error that say something like array needed but i insert ArrayCollection.. but now it work fine for me!!!!!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Simplest way:

```
$arr = $arrayCollectionInc->toArray();

foreach ($arr as $Inc) {

}
```

Working example:

```
$a = new ArrayCollection();
$a->add("value1");
$a->add("value2");

$arr = $a->toArray();

foreach ($arr as $a => $value) {
    echo $a . " : " . $value . "<br />";
}
```

Result:

```
0 : value1
1 : value2
```

Answer (score 47):

To those who find this question in the future there is another way that I would consider to be a better practice than the accepted answer, which just converts the `ArrayCollection` to an array. If you are going to just convert to an array why bother with the `ArrayCollection` in the first place?

You can easily loop over an `ArrayCollection` without converting it to an array by using the `getIterator()` function.

```
foreach($arrayCollection->getIterator() as $i => $item) {
    //do things with $item
}
```

Comment: This should be considered best practice.

Comment: Why exactly? ArrayCollection implements IteratorAggregate. You should just foreach the array collection

Comment: One difference I found is that if you don't use getIterator() and you do `$arrayCollection->key()` inside the loop, you always get `0`. But of course you can just do `as $i => $item` and you'll have your key without the need to call `key()`.

Answer (score 6):

Definitely agree one shouldn't convert to an array, however, `->getIterator()` isn't necessary.

```
foreach($arrayCollection as $i => $item) {
    //do things with $item
}
```

Comment: Have managed doing something like foreach($arrayCollection as $item) {// do something with $item} and it works just fine. Is there a performance difference that I'm missing, or an error I haven't encountered so far?